# walletAdapter documentation lacking/doesn't exist(yet?)

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, walletadapter, documentation

Wallet adapter is the typical entry point for any dApp, connect your wallet, and do some fun stuff. Yet, when looking for references of methods/classes, there is no longer existing documentation, this wasn't the case about a year ago.
e.g.
to see what I'm seeing

1. go to https://solana-labs.github.io/wallet-adapter/modules.html
2. click any of the modules, there are no modules/functions outlined except a reference of where the module is defined

My one question

1. is there an alternate way to build docs with all methods/classes/modules listed?

**DONT ANSWER QUESTION 2 AND 3, OTHERWISE IT WON'T BE A SPECIFIC QUESTION I'M ASKING PER @steveluscher**

2. why would documentation such as wallet adapter not be thoroughly checked? this leads to searching for outdated code examples / reading through source code to see what methods/attributes are available.
3. In the FAQ, there's a link for boiler plate code: https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/blob/master/APP.md but even here there's lack of explanation. Again, adding fuel to the fire, where is the explanation of methods such as `sendTransaction`...

```
import { WalletNotConnectedError } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-base';
import { useConnection, useWallet } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react';
import { Keypair, SystemProgram, Transaction } from '@solana/web3.js';
import React, { FC, useCallback } from 'react';

export const SendSOLToRandomAddress: FC = () => {
    const { connection } = useConnection();
    const { publicKey, sendTransaction } = useWallet();
    // rest omitted
}
```

**DONT ANSWER QUESTION 2 AND 3, OTHERWISE IT WON'T BE A SPECIFIC QUESTION I'M ASKING PER @steveluscher**

edit/re @steveluscher:  no a comment nor a request is needed for this package, I just want to know if there's a way to build the docs with all methods/classes/modules :) don't want to open a feature request issue nor create a separate question when this one has context, the 2) and 3) were just follow up questions. thanks :D

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, with the following advice:

1. If you have a comment or request about the development of `@solana/wallet-adapter`, open a [feature request issue](https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md&title=) on their Github
2. If you make a separate Stack Exchange post for each specific question that you have they'll get answered more quickly and will show up in more searches